# What could be wrong ? Getting WebServiceTransportException- 500

Tags: web-services, spring, soapui, spring-ws

I am trying to write a web-service client with Spring-WS 2.0.4.RELEASE, SOAP-1.2 , JAXB-2.1, Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE .

When I make a request to the web-service from my spring bean, I am getting the below exception trace.

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException:  [500]
                at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:663)
                at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:587)
                at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
                at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:384)
                at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:378)
                at com.comp.proj.services.common.impl.MailClientImpl.postMail(MailClientImpl.java:66)
```

My spring bean definitions are :

```
<bean id="mailServiceClient" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate" >
        <constructor-arg ref="emailSoapMsgFactory" type="org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessageFactory" />
        <property name="defaultUri" value="http://server:8080/Process/EmailNotifyService"/>
        <property name="marshaller" ref="emailJAXBBMarshaller"></property>
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="emailJAXBBMarshaller"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emailJAXBBMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
       <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.comp.proj.common.dto.EMailInputType</value>
                <value>com.comp.proj.common.dto.EMailOutputType</value>                
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

     <!-- Message factory for the service template. -->
     <bean id="emailSoapMsgFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
        <property name="soapVersion">
            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The confusion is when I try to post the same message (extracted from debug log) **in SoapUI it works perfect.**
I am not sure as to what could be causing this issue (from the stack trace).

Can it be some library issue ? Any help is much appreciated.

Appending Logs as per request:

```
SOAP UI RAW-Tab data:
---------------------
POST http://server:8080/Process/EmailNotifyService HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="/ActionURL"
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: server:8080
Content-Length: 11117
```

SOAP UI Log:

```
------------
1:49:34,627 DEBUG [HttpConnection] Open connection to server:8080
1:49:34,630 DEBUG [header] >> "POST /Process/EmailNotifyService HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,631 DEBUG [HttpMethodBase] Adding Host request header
1:49:34,639 DEBUG [header] >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,639 DEBUG [header] >> "Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="/ActionURL"[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,639 DEBUG [header] >> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,640 DEBUG [header] >> "Host: server:8080[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,640 DEBUG [header] >> "Content-Length: 11117[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,640 DEBUG [header] >> "[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,643 DEBUG [EntityEnclosingMethod] Request body sent
1:49:34,767 DEBUG [header] << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,768 DEBUG [header] << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,770 DEBUG [header] << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,771 DEBUG [header] << "Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,772 DEBUG [header] << "Content-Length: 437[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,774 DEBUG [header] << "Date: Wed, 20 Jun 2012 07:49:34 GMT[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,776 DEBUG [header] << "[\r][\n]"
1:49:34,785 DEBUG [HttpMethodBase] Resorting to protocol version default close connection policy
1:49:34,785 DEBUG [HttpMethodBase] Should NOT close connection, using HTTP/1.1
1:49:34,786 DEBUG [HttpConnection] Releasing connection back to connection manager.
1:49:34,788 DEBUG [IdleConnectionHandler] Adding connection at: 1340178574788
1:49:34,825 INFO  [AbstractHttpRequestDesktopPanel] Got response for [MailNotifyEventSourceBinding.NotifyEmail:Request 1] in 168ms (437 bytes)
```

### Application Debug Log:

```
2012-06-20 11:42:27,975 DEBUG: org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate - Opening [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpConnection@19c5ce6] to [http://server:8080/Process/EmailNotifyService]
2012-06-20 11:42:28,032 DEBUG: org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils - SOAPElement [com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.Envelope1_2Impl] implements SAAJ 1.3
2012-06-20 11:42:28,045 DEBUG: org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils - SOAPElement [com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.Body1_2Impl] implements SAAJ 1.3
2012-06-20 11:42:28,083 DEBUG: org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent - Sent request [<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><env:Header/><env:Body><ns2:input_Mail_Type xmlns:ns2="http://www.namespace.com/modified"><ns2:cc/><ns2:plainData>           
    &lt;!-- Outermost table --&gt;&#13;
                &lt;table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="700"&#13;
                    style="border:1px solid #c9c1b5; background:#f1eee7;"&gt;&#13;
                    &lt;tr&gt;&#13;
                        &lt;td&gt;&#13;
                        &lt;/td&gt;&#13;
                    &lt;/tr&gt;&#13;
                &lt;/table&gt;          &#13;
</ns2:plainData><ns2:subject>Test</ns2:subject><ns2:To>b@b.com</ns2:To><ns2:contentType>text/html</ns2:contentType><ns2:app_id>x01</ns2:app_id><ns2:username>x</ns2:username><ns2:password>x</ns2:password></ns2:input_Mail_Type></env:Body></env:Envelope>
2012-06-20 11:42:28,189 DEBUG: httpclient.wire.header - >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
2012-06-20 11:42:28,190 DEBUG: httpclient.wire.header - >> "Accept: application/soap+xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2[\r][\n]"
2012-06-20 11:42:28,191 DEBUG: httpclient.wire.header - >> "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
2012-06-20 11:42:28,192 DEBUG: httpclient.wire.header - >> "Content-Length: 11342[\r][\n]"
2012-06-20 11:42:28,192 DEBUG: httpclient.wire.header - >> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1[\r][\n]"
2012-06-20 11:42:28,193 DEBUG: httpclient.wire.header - >> "Host: server:8080[\r][\n]"
2012-06-20 11:42:28,292 DEBUG: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod - Request body sent
2012-06-20 11:42:28,295 DEBUG: httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 500 [\r][\n]"
2012-06-20 11:42:28,295 DEBUG: httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 500 [\r][\n]"
2012-06-20 11:42:28,318 DEBUG: org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate - Received error for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.namespace.com/modified}input_Mail_Type]
2012-06-20 11:42:28,320 DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/5.5.25 - Error report</title> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/5.5.25</h3></body> </html>"
```

Comment: If the message is the same, then probably the error is due to how you set up the web service connection. Eg encoding, soap version, etc. You should post more details, eg logged http conversation for both soapUI and spring.

Comment: @IstvanDevai Thanks.I shall collect the log and post it.

Comment: It took me along time to notice it but the XML view of the SOAP request also has a Raw View tab from which you can copy all the settings used by SoapUI (you can see the actual headers).

Comment: @IstvanDevai , @chrismead , I have appended the log to my question as per you request. I can see that "action" is not set in the HTTP request from my application.But I am using SoapActionCallback to set it when calling `mailServiceClient.marshalSendAndReceive`

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but hope it helps someone. 
Had this error, when spring-ws was not sending SoapAction with marhsalSendAndRecieve(). Bad thing was, that this situation is not logged anywhere and finally located with Fiddler, that only diffrence between SoapUI and webservice requests was missing SoapAction.

Added WebServiceMessageCallback to webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndRecieve to set SoapAction to message:

```
template.marshalSendAndReceive( serviceURL, jaxbRequest, 
                                new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
    @Override
    public void doWithMessage( WebServiceMessage message ) 
                                    throws IOException, TransformerException {
        ( (SoapMessage) message ).setSoapAction( "/mySoapAction" );
    }
}
```

Comment: After 8 years this answer still works, Love you man :)

Comment: It helped me also after 10 years... I had exactly the same problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem, with almost no stacktrace details.  Turned out it was a validation exception with the data I was sending into the request through the client.  For example, in SOAPUI:

.. in code I would send null, which would err, but if I send "" this works.